# How to set noindex for Google only?

Tags: html, indexing, meta-tags, googlebot, noindex

These days Google has this tag I can use to tell it not to index a page

```html
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
```

My question is do I need both the generic index and the Google noindex tags and does the order matter?

Suppose I want everyone else to index the page but Google, will setting both tags work:

```html
<meta name="robots" content="index"/>
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

absolutely correct: [Google's own documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710) is referencing an exactly this possibility.

Comment: So the order doesn't matter and both tags can be used at the same time?

Comment: These are different tags - yes, usable in any order